# Solving X'=AX with a Repeated root

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given the Matrix 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}2&2&1\\1&3&1\\1&2&2\end{bmatrix},
$$
I want to solve $X'=AX$. I got the first step by finding the eigenvalues of the matrix, which are: $\lambda = \{1,1,5\}$ and these are right since the sum of the eigenvalues are equal to the trace of the matrix. $(1+1+5=2+3+2) $

Next I got the Eigenvectors, I had no issue for $\lambda=5$ but with $\lambda=1$ is where I get a little confused when writing the solution $X(t)$. The Nullspace for $A-1I$ ends up being: $N(A-1I)= \{(-2,1,0), (-1,0,1)\}$.

Would I write my solution as the following: 
$$
X(t)= c_1 e^{t} (-2,1,0) + c_2 e^{t} (-1,0,1) + c_3 e^{5t} (1,1,1).
$$
Is the  "t" I have to put in the solution?

Please give me feed back on what to do when a case like this happens. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The solution you wrote is correct. On a minor note, the nullspace is not what you wrote but the *span* of $(-2,1,0)$ and $(-1,0,1)$.

The nontrivial case (not in this problem) occurs when the dimension of $N(A-\lambda I)$ does not agree with the multiplicity, for instance you have eigenvalues  $1,1,5$ but $N(A- 1I)$ has dimension one. In that case you need to look into the generalized eigenspaces.